# clicking on link does not do anything

Tags: html

Im trying to figure out how to make my sidebars main category list clickable.

Well, it is clickable, but, when i click on any of main categories elements it does not redirect me to page i need.

Layout:

```
@foreach($kat as $kategorijas)

            <li>
                <a href="kategorija/{{$kategorijas->id}}">{{$kategorijas->nosaukums}}</a> <-----here, this link doesnt respond, if i clode <li> tag here ir responds
                <div>
                    <p><strong style="font-size: 14px">{{$kategorijas->nosaukums}}</strong></p>
                    <ul>        

                        @foreach($kategorijas->apakskategorija as $apakskategorijas)
                            <li><a href="kategorija/{{ $kategorijas->id }}/apakskategorija/{{$apakskategorijas->id}}">{{$apakskategorijas->nosaukums}}</a></li>  <!-- <span>({{ $kategorijas->apakskategorija->count() }})</span> -->
                        @endforeach

                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </li>

        @endforeach
```

But, when i clode `<li>`tag right after `<a>` tag, it works fine, but my layout changes and is not like i want it to be.

**Render link, hope it is working:** http://rendera.herokuapp.com/usercode/cd6e038e956c0dd390d40bee3591597c26ff464e

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please

Comment: @j08691 sorry, forgot about it

Comment: Don't place links directly. Use `{{ url() }}` to generate proper links.